# What would be the best way to reformat a url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, formatting

I want to change /index.php?page=X to /X and /index.php?page=articles&article=X to /articles/X

What would be the best way?

Comment: mod_rewrite + regular expressions.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm very new to regex.